# Does $i = -\frac{(2\;W({\pi\over2}))}{\pi}$

Tags: complex-numbers, arithmetic, logarithms, pi, lambert-w

Let $x = -\frac{(2\;W({\pi\over2}))}{\pi}$, where $W$ denotes the Lambert W-function.

As
$${\log(i^2)\over i} = \pi$$
and $${\log(x^2)\over x}=\pi$$

Does $x = i$?

Comment: For the principal branch of W, the right-hand-side is real.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:assume $x=a+ib$ then $${\log(x^2)\over x}=\pi\to \pi(a+ib)=\log(x^2)=\ln(|x^2|)+i\arg(x^2)=2\mathrm{Ln}(|x|)+i2\arg(x)$$$$\to \begin{cases}
2\ \ln(|\sqrt{a^2+b^2}|)=\pi a \\
\pi b=2\arg(x) \\
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Shouldn't that be $\tan^{-1}(\frac{b}{a})$?

Comment: You should leave $\pi b=2\arg (x)$.  The equality $\arg (x)=\tan ^{-1}(x)$ doesn't always hold: while for $x=1+i$, we do have $\arg (x)=\tan ^{-1}(x)$, for  $x=-1+i=\sqrt{2}e^{i\frac{3\pi }{4}}$ we have $$\arg (x)=\arg \left( \sqrt{2}e^{i\frac{3\pi }{4}}\right) =\frac{3\pi }{4}$$ and $$\tan ^{-1}(x)=\tan ^{-1}\left( \frac{1}{-1}\right) =-
\frac{\pi }{4}.$$

Comment: @Américo Tavares:thanks

Comment: You are welcome!